# Flutter - myFile not in scope when I run print(myFile.absolute.path)

Tags: android, ios, dart, storage, flutter

I've been working on a piece of code in Flutter to save a specified variable to a text file. This works by simply pressing a button. To make this happen, Im using the `path_provider` dependency

**This is what that code looks like:**

```
trailing: new IconButton(
  icon: new Icon(Icons.add),
  onPressed: () async { 
    Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
    new File('$appDocPath/my_file.txt')
        .writeAsStringSync('myVar: $_currencies');  
    print(myFile.absolute.path);
  }
),
```

It would be difficult to past all my code here, as to execute a stable build I need a lot of code. **Instead, I've made a Git repository available here:**
https://github.com/Jak3-02/myproject2

I expect a new file called `my_file.txt` to be created but I can't find it. Also, I expect the following code to return what has been saved to the file, so I can see if the file has been created.

```
print(myFile.absolute.path);
```

But rather, I get the error:

```
[dart] Undefined name 'myFile'
```

I would expect the output to be along the lines of `myVar: Bitcoin` or `myVar: Ethereum`, but as I'm getting these errors I obviously cannot test this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the result of the `new File(...)` to a variable:

```
var myFile = new File('$appDocPath/my_file.txt')
```

and use `..` to get the result of `new File(...)` assigned instead of the result of `.writeAsStringSync(...)`

```
    new File('$appDocPath/my_file.txt')
        ..writeAsStringSync('myVar: $_currencies');
```

so together

```
    var myFile = new File('$appDocPath/my_file.txt')
        ..writeAsStringSync('myVar: $_currencies');
```

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you very much for all your help